Socket.io not receiving data properly in React and Node JS
`I am trying to build a connection between a web application and a frontend using socket.io. I want it so that anytime I click on a button, I receive the JSON data that is being sent from the server side (web app) to the client (frontend). The server side is built with express/node and the client is built with react.
I click on the first button, and the JSON message "hello" appears. When I click "done with JSON", I do not get another JSON message and instead get "Done with JSON" Anyone know how to solve this?
//////server side
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const { Server } = require('socket.io');



const app = express();
const server = app.listen(8080);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
    }
});
PORT = 8080;


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Socket.IO Server Running');
});

io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
    console.log("Connected");

      //this messsage is sent and received by the client
    const firstJson = {message:"hello"};
    socket.emit("receiveJson", firstJson);

    socket.on('jsonProcessed', () => {
        console.log('Client has processed the first JSON.');
        setTimeout(() => {
                  //this message is not received by the client
            const secondJson = { message: 'This is your second JSON!' };
            socket.emit('receiveJson', secondJson);
        }, 1000); // 1-second delay
    });
    
    socket.on('disconnect', ()=>{
        console.log('User disconnected');
    });
});



//Client side
import React, {useRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const Male = ({title})=>{
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const socket = io('http://localhost:8080');

   
        const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState(null);

        useEffect(()=>{
            socket.on('connect',()=>{
                console.log('Connection to server established');
            })
            socket.on('receiveJson',(data)=>{
                console.log('Received JSON from server: ', data);
                setJsonData(data);

            })
            return()=>{
                console.log("Disconnected from socket");
                socket.disconnect();
            }
        },[]);

        const handleJsonProcessing = () =>{
            console.log('Emitting jsonProcessed event');
            
            socket.emit('jsonProcessed');
            setJsonData(null);
        };
return(

</div>
                        {jsonData ? (
                <div>
                    <pre>{JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 2)}</pre>
                    <button onClick={handleJsonProcessing}>Done with JSON</button>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <p>No JSON data received.!!</p>
            )}
);
};


It might also help if I show my console statements, which come up here:[log statements](https://i.sstatic.net/X9eFBDcg.png)

Here's an updated version that should work:
// server
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const app = express();
const server = app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 8080");
});

const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Socket.IO Server Running");
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Connected");

  // This message is sent and received by the client
  const firstJson = { message: "hello" };
  socket.emit("receiveJson", firstJson);

  socket.on("jsonProcessed", () => {
    console.log("Client has processed the first JSON.");
    setTimeout(() => {
      // This message is not received by the client
      const secondJson = { message: "This is your second JSON!" };
      socket.emit("receiveJson", secondJson);
    }, 1000); // 1-second delay
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("User disconnected");
  });
});


// client
import io from "socket.io-client";
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Male = ({ title }) => {
  const socket = useRef(null);
  const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = io("http://localhost:8080");

    socket.current.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("Connection established");
    });
    
    socket.current.on("receiveJson", (data) => {
      console.log("Received: ", data);
      setJsonData(data);
    });
    
    return () => {
      console.log("Disconnected");
      socket.current.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  const handleProcessing = () => {
    console.log("Emitting event");
    socket.current.emit("jsonProcessed");
    setJsonData(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {jsonData ? (
        <div>
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 2)}</pre>
          <button onClick={handleProcessing}>Done</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>No data received.</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Male;


Thanks for the help, but I tried this and still get the same thing where the first message shows up, but upon the button click I get "no JSON data received" The console shows the object coming up twice, but it's the same "Hello" JSON.

I've updated the code, it should be working now.
The main changes are:
Socket Initialization is now inside a useRef hook.
useEffect has an empty dependency array, ensuring connection is only initialized once.
socket.current makes sure you're using the same socket instance.

Thanks so much! That fixed it, using the same socket instance makes sense as well
